# SendGrid dynamic template contains empty data - .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I am trying to send an email with a specific dynamic template and data. Email is successfully sent but contains empty data. The handle method is part of Azure Function. Recently I've changed Newtonsoft JSON to System.Text.Json and maybe this causes some problems.

**Email:**
[image]

**SendGrid dynamic template configuration:**
[image]

**C# Code:**

```
        public async Task Handle(SendEmailCommand command)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(emailConfig.SendGridApiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage();

            msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress(emailConfig.Sender));
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(command.To));
            msg.SetTemplateId(command.SendGridTemplateId);

            if (command.SendGridDynamicTemplateData != null)
            {
                var templateData = new TemplateData();

                command.SendGridDynamicTemplateData.TryGetValue("topic", out var topic);
                command.SendGridDynamicTemplateData.TryGetValue("email", out var email);
                command.SendGridDynamicTemplateData.TryGetValue("name", out var name);
                command.SendGridDynamicTemplateData.TryGetValue("message", out var message);

                templateData.Topic = topic.ToString();
                templateData.Email = email.ToString();
                templateData.Name = name.ToString();
                templateData.Message = message.ToString();

                msg.SetTemplateData(templateData);
            }

            await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }

        private class TemplateData
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("topic")]
            public string Topic { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("message")]
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same thing. The `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute from `System.Text.Json` doesn't seem to be recognized by the SendGrid API. I had to use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute from `Newtonsoft.Json` in order to get the parameters to appear on the email.

Comment: It looks like SendGrid API doesn't work properly with System.Text.Json which is a recommended serializer for .NET Core right now (faster than Newtonsoft.Json)

Comment: Even worse it appears api will not let you just give them the JSON directly